# Комбинированный режим switch

Tags: php

Хотел сделать комбинированный режим PHP+HTML с конструкцией switch, но я как всегда сделал ошибку.
Что я сделал не так?

```html
<?php 
$a = 2;             
?>

<?php  switch($a): ?>     

<?php case 1: ?>            
<div class =""> вода </div>
<?php break; ?>              
     
     
<?php case 2: ?>  
<div class =""> дерево </div>
<?php break; ?>  


<?php default:  ?>                   
<div class =""> ничего не найдено </div>
<?php break; ?>  

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

Код без пробелов:

```html
<?php 
$a = 2;             
?>
<?php switch($a): ?>    
<?php case 1: ?>            
<div class ="">вода</div>
<?php break; ?>                 
<?php case 2: ?>  
<div class ="">дерево</div>
<?php break; ?>  
<?php default: ?>                   
<div class ="">ничего не найдено</div>
<?php break; ?>  
<?php endswitch; ?>
```

Comment: а что выводится по итогу?

Comment: Нет, это вы должны сказать что не так

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INLINE_HTML " ", expecting "endswitch" or "case" or "default"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из **[документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)**:

> **Внимание**
>
> Любой вывод (включая пробельные символы) между выражением switch и
> первым case приведут к синтаксической ошибке. Например, данный код не
> будет работать:
>
> ```
> <?php switch ($foo): ?>
>     <?php case 1: ?>
>     ... 
> <?php endswitch ?>
> ```

> В то же время следующий пример будет работать, так как завершающий перевод строки после выражения switch
> считается частью закрывающего ?> и следовательно ничего не выводится
> между switch и case:
>
> ```
> <?php switch ($foo): ?> 
> <?php case 1: ?>
> ... 
> <?php endswitch ?>
> ```

В конце строк у вас полно пробелов. Между строк тоже.

Comment: Да у меня вроде код оформлен как в вашем втором варианте, все в столбик без пробелов

Comment: Абсолютно нет....... и прочитайте ещё раз последние два слова и предлог в ответе

Comment: убрал пробелы все равно не помогло.

Comment: Вы обманываете......вы не всё убрали.....удалите пустые строки...например и выложите код который сделали куда либо и дайте ссылку

Comment: Вот скрин все без пробелов: https://ibb.co/HCDBzQy

Comment: код выложите в песочницу и дайте ссылку....

Comment: Выложил в свою тему

Comment: Отлично....а теперь ещё:  читайте первые два слова в моём последнем предложении (с предлогом)

Comment: Да я везде, где можно убрал пробелы. Я не понимаю, где еще надо убрать

Comment: В вашем же вопросе они есть........что не ясного в **пробелы в конце строки** ? Вы знаете что такое пробелы? А знаете что такое конец строки?

Comment: А где пробелы? Можете указать конкретное место в коде.

Comment: Абсолютно везде....в конце **каждой** строки

Comment: Так оказывается нужно было убрать пробелы между switch и первым case. А вы говорите, что нужно убрать везде пробелы. Чего морочите голову, так бы и сказали сразу.

Comment: Ткните в предложение, где я написал, что надо убрать везде пробелы? Или извиняйтесь

Comment: "В конце строк у вас полно пробелов. Между строк тоже" этими словами вы как бы намекаете мне, что нужно убрать везде пробелы, тем самым вводя меня в заблуждение.  Но я все равно благодарен вам за оказанное содействие.

Comment: "этими словами вы как бы намекаете " --- то, что вы себе придумали в голове, и то, что написно - разные вещи. Надо внимательнее читать. Там написано то, что написано, а не то, что вы придумали